# read files using local macros in a loop in Stata

Tags: stata

I'm stuck trying to do a loop to read many files that have no correlated names, but I want to `save` them with correlated names.
This is an example of what I have:

```
paths: 
"example_84745.dta"
"example_74632.dta"
"example_18390.dta"
```

So, I want to read all of them and save them like

```
"example_1.dta"
"example_2.dta"
"example_3.dta"
```

What I'm trying to do is to work with local macros, like this:

```
local path_1 = "example_84745.dta"
local path_2 = "example_74632.dta"
local path_3 = "example_18390.dta"

forvalues i = 1(1)3{

display "path_`i'"
use "path_`i'", clear 

save "example_`i'"

}
```

But it is not working. It prints `path_1 is not found`.

I really appreciate your comments.

Answer (score 1):

You're looping over `1 2 3` and asking to display `path_1 path_2 path_3` and then use them, but you need to spell out that they are in turn local macro names.

```
local path_1 = "example_84745.dta"
local path_2 = "example_74632.dta"
local path_3 = "example_18390.dta"

forvalues i = 1(1)3{

display "`path_`i''"
use "`path_`i''", clear 

save "example_`i'"

}
```

Local macros in Stata can be used like variables in many programming languages, but it is not customary to regard them as variables. In Stata, a variable is (is only) a column in a dataset.